# SQLAlchemy, eager load postgresql INET/CIDR relationships

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables in postgresql, one named `ip_address`, and another named `network`.

The `ip_address` table has two columns:

1. `id` is an `INTEGER`
2. `v4address` is an `INET`

The `network` table has two columns:

1. `id` is an `INTEGER`
2. `v4representation` is a `CIDR`

I want to be able to select an `ip_address` and eagerly load the `ip_addresses` `network`(s) without having to define an `id` based foreign key relationship between the tables. The `id` columns are used by other, unrelated relationships to other tables.

The SQL to accomplish this is:

```
select * from ip_address join network on ip_address.v4address << network.v4representation;
```

In postgresql, the `<<` operator can be used to compare an `INET` and a `CIDR`. It will match rows where the `INET` is contained within the `CIDR`.

I can define a `property` on my `IPAddress` model which will accomplish this:

```
@property
def networks(self):
    query = session.query(Network)
    query = query.filter("v4representation >> :v4addr").params(v4addr=self.v4address)
    return query.all()
```

This works, but then when I'm actually attempting to use this `property` in an application, I experience the typical "N + 1" queries problem. I'd like to define this in such a way as to be able to eager load an ip addresses networks.

I've tried to define it as a `relationship` using `primaryjoin`, but can't figure out what's needed. I've tried this:

```
networks = db.relationship("Network",
                           primaryjoin='IPAddress.v4address << Network.v4representation',
                           viewonly=True)
```

But sqlalchemy doesn't know what to do with the `<<` operator, so I've switched to this:

```
networks = db.relationship("Network",
                           primaryjoin='IPAddress.v4address.op("<<")(Network.v4representation)',
                           viewonly=True)
```

But sqlalchemy throws an `ArgumentError`:

```
ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition 'public.ip_address.v4address << public.network.v4representation' on relationship IPAddress.networks.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.
```

I've tried several combinations of defining a `foreign_key` for the `relationship`:

```
networks = db.relationship("Network",
                           primaryjoin='IPAddress.v4address.op("<<")(Network.v4representation)',
                           foreign_keys='[Network.v4representation]',
                           viewonly=True)
```

But sqlalchemy throws `ArgumentErrors`:
    ArgumentError: Relationship IPAddress.networks could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.

Neither specifying `IPAddress.v4address` or `Network.v4representation` as a `remote_side` changes the exception.

No attempts at annotating the `primaryjoin` condition with `foreign`/`remote` has helped either.

Coming back to my original intent, I want to be able to perform a query which will return ip addresses and eager load their networks (and possibly data from the networks other relations, as this is a simplification of my full schema).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the missing piece here is that the custom operator isn't working within the relationship framework.  To assist in this case I've added a new feature for SQLAlchemy 0.9.2 which is the "is_comparison" flag, and an example is here, at [Using custom operators in join conditions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#using-custom-operators-in-join-conditions).

Here is a version that accomplishes this same result using less public APIs, which will work in 0.8 also:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INET, CIDR

Base = declarative_base()

# workaround before 0.9.2
from sqlalchemy.sql import operators
is_contained_by = operators.custom_op("<<")
operators._comparison.add(is_contained_by)

class IPA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ip_address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    v4address = Column(INET)

    network = relationship("Network",
                        primaryjoin=lambda: is_contained_by(
                                     IPA.v4address, 
                                     (foreign(Network.v4representation))
                                    ),
                        viewonly=True
                    )
class Network(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'network'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    v4representation = Column(CIDR)

print Session().query(IPA).join(IPA.network)
```

In 0.9.2 and greater, it can be done as:

```
class IPA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ip_address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    v4address = Column(INET)

    network = relationship("Network",
                        primaryjoin="IPA.v4address.op('<<', is_comparison=True)"
                            "(foreign(Network.v4representation))",
                        viewonly=True
                    )
```